# validate date inputs in jquery ui datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

Please I am using jquery ui datepicker as part of my asp.net application. The challenge I am having right now is how I can validate the input in the associated text box if it is typed in manually.

For instance if a user just types in digit i.e 1223333 the application just blows up with a code error.

I reckon client site validation would do. Please kindly assist.

Thanks,

Shola

Comment: I think `Jquery datepicker` doesn't let user to type in the `Input textbox`  by defalut.

Comment: you need to write your own client side validation in either javascript or jquery. If not, as a work around make the textbox readonly by which you can force the user to enter the date only using datepicker.